# Is there a git command to show what files are commited/edited by who?

Tags: git

Is there a git command to show what files are commited/edited by who ?

Output should be like:

```
FileName AuthorName

fileA user1 user2 
fileB user 3 
fileC user1
```

Comment: git log will do it, google for the rest

Comment: @EngineerDollery git log gives a very mess output. Is there a way to extract the information w/o file processing ?

Comment: As far as I understand the question you wish to collect committers (or authors? or both?) names, for each file in a repo, during the entire history of the repo, right? Or, maybe, just to collect "actual" authors/committers (i.e. those who created at least one line in the _current_ state of files)?

Comment: Edited the question. Hope it's clearer. Your first assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with a single git command.

In `sh`, `bash`, or `zsh` you can do this:

```sh
git ls-files -z | xargs --null -L1 -I % sh -c "printf %' '; git annotate -p % | sed -nr '/^author /{s/^author (.*)/\1/;p}' | sort | uniq | awk '{printf (\$0 \" \")}END{print \"\"}'"
```

Or, more readable: Create a script file `print_file_and_its_authors.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf $1' '  # Output filename without appending a line break.

# Output file authors and a line break:
git annotate -p $1 \
    | sed -nr '/^author /{s/^author (.*)/\1/;p}' \
    | sort | uniq \
    | awk '{printf ($0 " ")}END{print ""}'
```

Then do:

```sh
chmod u+x print_file_and_its_authors.sh
git ls-files -z | xargs --null -L1 ./print_file_and_its_authors.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use your own `git log --pretty=format` options.

In the `--pretty` you can set colors and choose any content you would like to display.

In your case you want to display the author - choose any of the

**%aX** - option based upon your needs.

---

> ***`format:<string>`***
>
> The format: format allows you to specify which information you want to show. It works a little bit like printf format, with the notable exception that you get a newline with %n instead of \n.
>
> E.g, format:`The author of %h was %an, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n` would show something like this:

```
The author of fe6e0ee was Junio C Hamano, 23 hours ago
The title was >>t4119: test autocomputing -p<n> for traditional diff input.<<
```

> ***`The placeholders are`***:
>
> `%C(…):` color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.
>
> `%C(…):` color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again.
>
> `%Cblue:` switch color to blue
>   `%Cgreen:` switch color to green
>   `%Cred:` switch color to red
>   `%Creset:` reset color
>   `%D:` ref names without the " (", ")" wrapping.
>   `%G?:` show "G" for a Good signature, "B" for a Bad signature, "U" for a good, untrusted signature and "N" for no signature
>   `%GG:` raw verification message from GPG for a signed commit
>   `%GK:` show the key used to sign a signed commit
>   `%GS:` show the name of the signer for a signed commit
>   `%H:` commit hash
>   `%N:` commit notes
>   `%P:` parent hashes
>   `%T:` tree hash
>   `%aD:` author date, RFC2822 style
>   `%aE:` author email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%aI:` author date, strict ISO 8601 format
>   `%aN:` author name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%ad:` author date (format respects --date= option)
>   `%ae:` author email
>   `%ai:` author date, ISO 8601-like format
>   `%an:` author name
>   `%ar:` author date, relative
>   `%at:` author date, UNIX timestamp
>   `%b:` body
>   `%cD:` committer date, RFC2822 style
>   `%cE:` committer email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%cI:` committer date, strict ISO 8601 format
>   `%cN:` committer name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%cd:` committer date (format respects --date= option)
>   `%ce:` committer email
>   `%ci:` committer date, ISO 8601-like format
>   `%cn:` committer name
>   `%cr:` committer date, relative
>   `%ct:` committer date, UNIX timestamp
>   `%d:` ref names, like the --decorate option of git-log(1)
>   `%e:` encoding
>   `%f:` sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
>   `%gD:` reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1}
>   `%gE:` reflog identity email (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%gN:` reflog identity name (respecting .mailmap, see git-shortlog(1) or git-blame(1))
>   `%gd:` shortened reflog selector, e.g., stash@{1}
>   `%ge:` reflog identity email
>   `%gn:` reflog identity name
>   `%gs:` reflog subject
>   `%h:` abbreviated commit hash
>   `%m:` left, right or boundary mark
>   `%n:` newline
>   `%p:` abbreviated parent hashes
>   `%s:` subject
>   `%t:` abbreviated tree hash
>   `%w([<w>[,<i1>[,<i2>]]]):` switch line wrapping, like the -w option of git-shortlog(1).
>   `%x00:` print a byte from a hex code

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific file or files, you could use `git log --pretty=%an -- some_file | sort -u` for each file to list the authors who edited this file. As to the output format you expect, you may take a furthur step. This command lists all the files of the current HEAD, including those which have been deleted, and their editors.

```
git log --pretty="/ %h" --name-only | grep -v ^$| grep -v ^/ | sort -u | while read line
do
authors=$(git log --pretty=%an -- "$line" | sort -u)
echo $line,$authors
done
```

The `git log --pretty="/ %h" --name-only | grep -v ^$| grep -v ^/ | sort -u` part is to find all the files including those which have been deleted. I think there must be some easier way.