# Git pull output with author of commit for each file

Tags: git

Would it be possible to get output of the `git pull` displayed with the last contributor/author for each file?

I would like to see who is responsible for the last change in the list of pulled files.

Comment: Conceptually in Git, _every_ file in a branch gets updated during a pull. Which files do you want to see stats for?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried googling and when no results similar to this case, I bravely posted here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a git command to show what files are commited/edited by who?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232026/is-there-a-git-command-to-show-what-files-are-commited-edited-by-who)

Comment: It's not duplicate if I am asking about printing these informations for the files being newly pulled only.

Answer (score 0):

`git log` has a lot of options, including showing author of the commit and a list of changed files. So doing `git log HEAD...origin` before dong `git pull` could give some idea about what has happened since the last pull.

Documentation of git-log: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log (check out [Pretty Formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) and [--numstat](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---numstat))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the details of each commit in each file theres a command

```
git show
```

This will show the complete details of commit diff.
git show [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show).
But as per your requirement you want to see the details when you do pull, which is not there on git documentation.